# problem in using ESAPI library for XSS prevention

Tags: security, xss, owasp

I am trying to prevent XSS attacks in my website for this i am using OWASP ESAPI library .I added jar for this  library in classpath and I am getting following error .

> Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via file io.
>   Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via file io.
>   Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: F:\eclipse\ESAPI.properties
>   Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: .esapi\ESAPI.properties
>   Not found in 'user.home' directory: C:\Users\juzer.esapi\ESAPI.properties
>   Loading ESAPI.properties via file io failed.
>   Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via the classpath.
>   ESAPI.properties could not be loaded by any means. fail.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Like the error suggests, you are missing ESAPI.properties. It needs to be in your classpath. After you deploy, make sure you can find it in WEB-INF/classes.

Here is an [example of ESAPI.properties](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/source/browse/trunk/src/test/resources/.esapi/ESAPI.properties?r=1210).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ESAPI.properties and antisamy-esapi.xml to your "your web app"/src/java directory.  When you build, it will be added to your classpath at "your web app"/build/web/WEB-INF/classes